# How can i clean my dataset from outliers as it includes numerical and categorical variables in Python?

Tags: python, outliers

I would like to clean my dataset from outliers but just in three specific columns, as the other 10 contain categorical variables. So how can I get my data cleaned by only referring to these specific columns?

I'd like to use iqr range method. That's the code i run so far:

```
import numpy as np
def outliers(x): 
       return np.abs(x- x.median()) > 1.5*(x.quantile(.75)-x.quantile(0.25))
ath2.Age[outliers(ath2.Age)]
ath2.Height[outliers(ath2.Height)]
ath2.Weight[outliers(ath2.Weight)]
```

After checking the number of outliers in the columns I'm interested in, I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: what is the error here??

Comment: @RahulAgarwal no errors up to this point. But then I need to remove outliers. I tried this code: ath2 = ath2[~ath2.apply(outliers).any(axis=1)]. But as there are also strings it cannot work on the entire dataset. How can i make it work on just these three columns?
TypeError: (ValueError("could not convert string to float: 'Olesya Nikolayevna Zykina'",), 'occurred at index Name')

Comment: What is the error u r getting when u r applying with just 3 columns as you have shown in your code. What is the problem with the above code u r trying?

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'median'

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the code to be dynamic, you can 1st check the columns which are not categorical by below code:

```
cols = df.columns
num_cols = df._get_numeric_data().columns 
##num_cols will contains list of column names which are numeric
## In your case, it should come Age,Height etc.
```

Alternatively, you can also use `include` or `exclude` parameters using `df.select_dtypes` according to your dataframe

After this  run below code from columns from above:

```
df[np.abs(df.Data-df.Data.mean()) <= (3*df.Data.std())]  
## Df is the dataframe and Data is the name of the column. 
#In your case, it will be Age,Height etc.
```

**OR**

If you want to make a new df with only the numerical columns and find out the outliers in one shot, below is the code:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: np.abs(x - x.mean()) / x.std() < 3).all(axis=1)]
```